# CSS styling a div to stand within a div (Chrome behavior)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm in the process of making a commercial website but I'm stuck.

So if you click the link above you should see a gradient graphic which I use to divide the logo and the text. Now if you open this in Google Chrome's latest version you should see that it's not properly displayed at the right of the logo.

**My HTML structure:**

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="/?lang=en">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="/assets/imagesets/logos.gif" alt="Winslow Logo" height="100" width="138" />
                <div class="side-border"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-container">
                <h1 class="tag">Winslow Hotels</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.header
{
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1% auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.logo
{
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}

div.logo-container
{
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.side-border
{
    width: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("/assets/imagesets/side-border.png");
}

div.text-container
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 660px;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 5em;
    padding: 1.5%;
}

div.menu-container
{
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 8%;
    left: 0px;
}
```

This code works in every other browser **except** Google Chrome. Is it a bug in Chrome or do I have to add hacks to my CSS to fix it?

**Edit:**

The `div.side-border` is not positioned next to `div.text-container` and does not appear within `div.logo-container`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem ***in the question*** or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. We shouldn't have to view another page to guess at what's wrong.

Comment: Ok I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with widths and floats. There's a lot of unnecessary code which I will not address, however, what I recommend to you is, use a `pseudo-selector` (`:after`) instead of a separate `div` (`.side-border`) to achieve your result:

```
.logo-container {
   position:relative;
}

.logo-container:after {
    width: 2px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("/assets/imagesets/side-border.png");
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; top: 0;
}
```

And remove `.side-border` from HTML and CSS.

---

**Edit:** on a second thought, this could be simplified even more. Just add your gradient-border image as a `background` to the `.logo-container` and position it to the right:

```
div.logo-container {
    width: 140px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("/assets/imagesets/side-border.png") no-repeat right;
}
```

Comment: This is the more elegant approach. A simpler solution using the existing code would have been `.logo-container img { float: left; }`

Comment: That fixed the problem.

Comment: `float: left;` is the simplest indeed.